# Problem Preserving Zoom Level on iPhone When Changing Pages in Iframe

Tags: iphone, zoom-sdk

I'm having a problem implementing a flipbook on my website, which is built using the Heyzine platform. The flipbook is properly integrated and displayed on the site, but I'm facing a specific issue on iPhones. Namely, when the user zooms in on the flipbook and tries to change the page, the flipbook automatically zooms out. This problem does not appear on Android devices or desktop computers, but only on some iPhone models (eg iPhone 15).

I used standard JavaScript and CSS to control the display of the iframe, but regardless, the problem remains.

Has anyone had a similar problem or can offer insight into potential solutions or workarounds that might help preserve the zoom level when switching pages in an iframe on iPhones? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!